# How to apply global styling to a react component library?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am developing a React Component Library and I am struggling to apply some global styles (like resetting things) to the global level to be applied to all my components.
For instance, my app JS is something like this.

```
import './styles.module.css';
import Button from './Components/Button';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import Input from './Components/Input';

export {
  Button,
  Navbar,
  Input,
}
```

and a generic global css file would be something like this:

```
:root {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I thought of using the  approach from `Styled Components` as well, but as I don't have anything wrapping my components (it's a library), I don't know exactly where/how to use it.
Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be the most elegant solution, but you could create a mixin (with default styles) and import it within each component.

In styled-component you could do it like this:

Define mixin in a file and export it

```
import { css } from 'styled-components';

export const defaultStyles = css`
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  // other default styles go here...
`
```

and then use it in each component like:

```
import styled from 'styled-component'
import {defaultStyle} from './path/to/file/from/where/you/export/defaultStyle'

const Button = styled.button`

  ${defaultStyles}
  
  border: none;
  // other commponent specific styles go here...
`
```